# When i input any letter, it just repeats(like it should), but when i input + or × or ÷ or *, it shouldn't repeat, when i did it with numbers it worked

Tags: python

```
semn = ""

def asemn():
    global semn
    if semn != '+' or '×' or '÷' or '*':
        semn = input("Semn:")
        print(semn)
        asemn()
asemn():
```

---

The code that I used for numbers:

```
def anum1():
        global num1
        if num1.isnumeric() == False:
            num1 = input("Primul numar:")
            anum1()
anum1()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You're mistaken about what `or` means in Python. See the above question.

Comment: Your `if` statement does not do what you think it does.  It is parsed `if (semn != '+') or '×' or '÷' or '*':` and since `'×'` is always true, the `if` will always be taken.  You need `if semn in '+×÷*':`